# Ionic Xcode unable to open file(target app)

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I haven't touched my Ionic projects in around 1-2 months.

All my projects were running perfectly then.

I go to try run them today and every single one of them is saying

```
Showing Recent Messages
/Users/jakelewis/Desktop/fifteen-project-e/ios/App/Pods/Target Support 
Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "App" in project "App")
```

They were all running perfectly. I haven't updated Xcode yet to the latest because it's still in the process of downloading. What would cause this issue?

It's a nightmare.

Somethings I tried, removing the ios folder and `npx cap add ios`

Even went on GitHub and went to rollback versions I knew that ran perfectly on IOS before.

I am using capacitor on most of my projects.

This did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 14):

1. close XCode
2. run `ionic capacitor copy ios` to build it.
3. run `pod reintegrate` and `pod install` (navigate to where the pod file is located first, ex: cd ios/App and then run "pod install" command)
4. open XCode again use `ionic capacitor open ios` command

This work for me

Comment: it's not pod reintegrate, actually it's pod deintegrate.

Comment: This with @AbdulJabbar's comment/update above worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

try this:

- Close XCode
- open a terminal, go to the project and execute
  `pod install` inside your app folder (where Podfile is located)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, still having the same issue. Any idea or workaround ?